# How to round up result of dividing

Tags: c#, math, rounding

```
finalResult = Math.Ceiling(result = (x - y) / (z - 1));
```

I am trying to get whole rounded number. finalResult and result are double. Others are int. And well... not working.
I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*? What are the input values and what is the *desired outcome*?

Comment: I would also advise making sure z != 1, otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Define "not working". It's not clear from your question and some context-less code what your actual problem is.

Comment: If `x, y, z` are `int` then there is nothing to ceil, the result is already an int

Comment: When describing a problem you should always clarify what "not working" means. In this case your question would have been improved by providing sample input (ie values of x, y, z) along with the actual output and your expected output. In this case "integer division" is such a common "gotcha" that people spotted it immediately but a good question includes everything needed for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already, and be sure to take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result of this operation as `double` you have to make at least one operand `double` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb.aspx). Try adding 'd' to literal:

```
finalResult = Math.Ceiling(result = (x - y) / (z - 1d));
```

By doing this little trick you ensure that '1' will be treated as `double`, not as `int`, so the whole operation outcome will be a `double`.
Note: Unless you want to round this value up, you should change the rounding method to `Math.Round()`.
Note 2: Make sure to prevent division by 0 by checking `if(z != 0)`.

Comment: You should explain *why* this helps as well.

Comment: Since it's now floating point, division by zero isn't really a big deal

Answer (score 2):

Since x, y and z are all `int`, then the division will be done as integer and will be truncated.

To avoid that, simply cast like so:

```
finalResult = Math.Ceiling(result = (x - y) / (double)(z - 1));
```

(I'm assuming here you want to round up, so if the result of the division was, say, 1.00001, you'd want the rounded result to be 2.0.)

Answer (score 1):

You need a type casting to get Math.Ceiling to work.

```
Decimal finalResult = Math.Ceiling(((Decimal)(x - y)) / (z - 1));
```

Comment: Your type casting comes too late. You are casting the result of `(x - y) / (z - 1)` but that has already done integer division by that point.

Comment: Moved inside ;)